# image can not load in gridview

Tags: android, uiimageview

i can not load imageview to grid view
all code is true but i can not load more 5 image

here the error show me when add new image

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.children_activities, PID: 8331
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.children_activities/com.children_activities.Image_show}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML
>   file line #2: Error inflating class 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:724)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:792)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.children_activities.Image_show.onCreate(Image_show.java:15)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24471564 byte allocation with 16772768 free bytes and 21MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:700)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:535)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1179)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:770)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1727)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:945)
>           at android.view.View.(View.java:4516)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:579)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:248)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:244)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:240)
>             ... 25 more

Comment: add your xml and java code

Comment: @Safaa Omar : To avoid OOM issue you need to optimize images or bitmaps. Please check this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the **`Caused by:`** lines, it looks like the root cause is an `OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24471564 byte allocation with 16772768 free bytes`

This is often resolved by allocating more heapspace to the application for it to process large images. 
This can be done by adding the following line of code to the manifest file:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using very large size images. You need to compress images before loading.
If you are setting images directly to view please use images for different screen sizes.
Please use Picasso or Glide image loading library.